# Can't connect to Access database ("architecture mismatch" error)

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

**A program to retrive records from database**

```
       import java.sql.*;
       import javax.sql.*;

public class Database 
{
    public static void main(String a\[\])
    {
        try
        {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection cn =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:data");
        Statement st=cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery("select * from student ");
        while(rs.next())
        {
            int r=rs.getInt(1);
            String n= rs.getString(2);
            int m=rs.getInt(3);
            System.out.println("Roll Name Marks");
            System.out.println(r+" "+n+" "+m);
        }
        cn.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}][1]
```

I am running 64 bit Windows 7 
Created the DSN from sysWOW64 folder
Have a database consisting of 3 fields Roll Name Mark
After Compiling no errors are found
Executing the program results in no Output
Why I am not able to Execute the program

![At command line no output][1]

**Edit from comments**

The exception I am getting is

> SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

Comment: use e.printStackTrace() in catch block, to see if any exception.

Comment: You are probably getting an exception at runtime but you cannot see it because of empty `catch` block. You must be sure Java, DSN and MS ODBC driver are all the same architecture either 32 or 64 bits. Otherwise you'll get compatibility issues.

Comment: this was the out put    java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contai
ns an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

Comment: That's what I'm talking about. Your Java architecture probably is 64 bits but accessing DSN through sysWOW64 is the 32 bits ODBC controller (if I remember right). Consequently you have architecture mismatch issues.

Comment: So what solution is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contai ns an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application
```

The problem is your Java architecture is probably 64-bits based but when you access`Odbcad32.exe` through this path:

```
%windir%\SysWoW64\odbcad32.exe
```

You're actually accessing the 32-bits version of the ODBC controller. Consequently you have architecture mismatch issues. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20775002/microsoftodbc-driver-manager-the-specified-dsn-contains-an-architecture-misma) for more details.

To make it work you must be sure Java, DSN and MS ODBC driver are all the same architecture either 32 or 64 bits.

So you can:

- Download a 32-bits JDK and leave the DSN you already have.
- Access the DSN directly from `%windir%\System32` folder (is the
  64-bits version) and create the data source there.

Comment: Should i get office 64 bit or jdk 32 bit...(jdk is 64 bit)

Comment: Exactly. I had the same issue before because my Office was 32-bits. I've downloaded jdk 32 bits and accessed DSN through the same path as you do. Then all was 32-bits based and it worked like a charm. @user3346898

Comment: thanks everything working like a charm

Answer (score -2):

When you receive no Java exception/error and no output, it seems you can connect to the database and it simply doesn't contain any data.

Comment: Nope it contains four recoeds

Comment: Exception may be there. But you have not printed that exception. SO no output may be there.

Comment: @user3346898 then you have to debug, we won't help you remotely without any concrete question regarding code.

Comment: i have used the cmd in the sysWoW64 folder still no o/p